# How do I generate React Kendo <GridColumn /> dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, kendo-react-ui

I'm trying to build a kendo grid using the new KendoReact library, and my render method is below.

```
render() {
    var allColumns = this.state.data.length > 0 ? Object.keys(this.state.data[0]) : []
    var columnsToShow = allColumns.map((item,i) => <GridColumn field={item} key={i} />);
    return (<div> 
        <Grid
            data={this.state.data}
        >
            {columnsToShow}

        </Grid>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Since GridColumns have to be defined (not automatic), I wanted to generate them dynamically, i.e. in line 3 `var columnsToShow`. Could someone help me understand why the columns don't show, but the data *does* render? (I know data is present because if I define it sepecifically `<GridColumn field="Name" />` it works.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the code above is fine. When using your dynamic creation of columns

```
var allColumns = this.state.data.length > 0 ? Object.keys(this.state.data[0]) : []
var columnsToShow = allColumns.map((item,i) => <GridColumn field={item} key={i} />);
```

inside the [official Kendo React Grid demo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/#toc-basic-usage) the columns are generated successfully. The columns titles could be changed via applying the `Title` prop on each column.